# Java Set JPanel Height To Percentage Of Window Height

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've been trying to set a jpanel's height to 80% of the window's height. Every way I do it creates either a small rectangle, or fills the whole window. Currently, this is my code;

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());  
window.setSize(xSize,ySize);
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setBackground(Color.PINK);
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
int gameHeight = (int)(Math.round(ySize * 100.0/window.getHeight()));
int gameWidth = (int)(Math.round(xSize * 100.0/window.getWidth()));
p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gameHeight, gameWidth));
p.add(new JLabel(" "));
window.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: I would just like to point something out. You should be setting the Frame to 80% if you want the window to be 80% of the screen size. Having a panel be 80% would mean the Frame would be about 82-85%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your math is slightly off.

To acquire 80% of a value, you should multiple it by `0.80`, so you would want the panel height to be `ySize * 0.80` and the panel width to be `xSize * 0.80`.

```
int gameHeight = (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.80));
int gameWidth = (int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.80));
p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gameWidth, gameHeight));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but in this, and Quirliom's answer, the panel takes up the whole window, even if I play around with the maths. And of course my maths is off, i'm useless lol

Comment: Do you call `pack()` on your frame object at any point? In order for the preferred size to take effect, you'll need to do so.  Alternatively, use `p.setSize(gameWidth, gameHeight)`.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that the height and width parameters are swapped; fixing that now in my answer.